# How to close datepicker after I select the time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have datetime piker

```
 <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
       <input size="16" type="text" readonly value="
  <%=UsersItem.StopDate.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")%>" id="StopDate" 
               name="StopDate" class="m-wrap" data-format="dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii">
       <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
 </div>
```

initialize in documend ready

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
                isRTL: false,
                format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii',
                pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
            });

});
```

After I select the date and time, calendar does not disappear.
[image]

how to make it go away? (with jquery verify length in textbox?)

Thx in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could separate the date and time into separate inputs? Seems awkward to put them in the same selector.

Comment: @Blazemonger I need date and time in the same input

Comment: Well, we can't help you without knowing how you're generating the picker. Please share more code.

Comment: @Alex - were you able to find a solution to this ?

Comment: @shabeer90 yes, in documentations, when initialize datepiker added autoclose:true